# Regex Not match all occurrences

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I wrote an app in C# using htmlagilitypack. That is parsing prices from a webpage.
The console oput looks like this;

```
RRP ?142 - Now ?113
?57.99&nbsp;nbsp<incl. VAT>$nbsp:
RRP ?50.00 - Now ?39.99
```

The problem which I am finding is that the regex which I wrote is picking up some of the first prices for the RRP and not the now price, The regex which I am using is below.

```
^[^£]*£(?:[0-9\.,]+)[^£]*£([0-9\.,]+)
```

I was just wondering why this is picking up some of the correct prices but not every single one. Thanks for any advice which you can give.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex i tried it and it seems fine

```
\w{1,}\s{1,}\?\d{1,}(.\d{1,}|)
```